# Howto convert org-mode table to original tabbed format?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am converting a region to a table by using `C-c |`.

Is there a way to reverse the process, say after converting do some editing and go back to original format (tab separated values will do)?

I know that I can do it via `org-table-export` but that is too cumbersome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Mark the region.
2. <kbd>M-x replace-string</kbd>
3. |
4. <kbd>C-q TAB RET</kbd>

If you want to tweak it, use `replace-regex`.

Comment: Yes, that should work, but is there an included `orgtbl` command to do this?  As the OP asked, something like an inverse `C-c |`.

Comment: Even more cumbersome than current workaround as told by OP

Answer (score 14):

Try `orgtbl-to-tsv` for tab-separated values.

There is also `orgtbl-to-csv` for comma-separated values.

Combining the table with a short code block to do the conversion is convenient. For example:

```
* Some heading
        
#+name: foo 
| a | b | c |
|---+---+---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
        

#+name: foo-csv
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var x=foo :wrap example
(orgtbl-to-csv x nil)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: foo-csv
#+begin_example
1,2,3
4,5,6
#+end_example
```

`C-c C-c` on the code block will produce the results shown. Adding `:colnames no` as a header argument to the code block will also preserve the header line:

```
#+name: foo-csv
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var x=foo :wrap example :results raw :colnames no
(orgtbl-to-csv x nil)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: foo-csv
#+begin_example
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
#+end_example
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the question wanted to avoid?  Typing first `org-table-export` and then choosing `orgtbl-to-tsv`.

Comment: Thank you, I don't seem to have these functions in my Emacs versioned _GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)_ of 2013-03-17 on MARVIN. Any ideas?

Comment: `orgtbl-to-tsv` and `org-tbl-to-csv` are part of Org mode since release_6.03 in 2008. They can be found in the file `lisp/org-table.el`. They should be available in any recent Emacs, although back in 2013 Org mode was probably not part of Emacs yet, so one would have had to install it manually.

Answer (score 8):

I needed this too and just wrote the following based on org-table-export:

```
(defun org-table-transform-in-place ()
  "Just like `ORG-TABLE-EXPORT', but instead of exporting to a
  file, replace table with data formatted according to user's
  choice, where the format choices are the same as
  org-table-export."
  (interactive)
  (unless (org-at-table-p) (user-error "No table at point"))
  (org-table-align)
  (let* ((format
      (completing-read "Transform table function: "
               '("orgtbl-to-tsv" "orgtbl-to-csv" "orgtbl-to-latex"
                 "orgtbl-to-html" "orgtbl-to-generic"
                 "orgtbl-to-texinfo" "orgtbl-to-orgtbl"
                 "orgtbl-to-unicode")))
     (curr-point (point)))
    (if (string-match "\\([^ \t\r\n]+\\)\\( +.*\\)?" format)
    (let ((transform (intern (match-string 1 format)))
          (params (and (match-end 2)
               (read (concat "(" (match-string 2 format) ")"))))
          (table (org-table-to-lisp
              (buffer-substring-no-properties
               (org-table-begin) (org-table-end)))))
      (unless (fboundp transform)
        (user-error "No such transformation function %s" transform))
      (save-restriction
        (with-output-to-string
          (delete-region (org-table-begin) (org-table-end))
          (insert (funcall transform table params) "\n")))
      (goto-char curr-point)
      (beginning-of-line)
      (message "Tranformation done."))
      (user-error "Table export format invalid"))))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "\C-x |") 'org-table-transform-in-place)
```

It'd be great if this got added to org-mode proper as I think many would use it.

Comment: One of my usage is exporting to clipboard and paste to a spreadsheet.

Comment: Works as expected, lovely!

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps to use export the table as tab or comma separated values:

1. Use the command org-table-export. `M-x org-table-export`
2. Enter the filename to save to (or hit enter for the same file).
3. Select the format (this is where you can set the orgtbl-to-tsv or any other formats).

These are some of the formats that can be used:

- orgtbl-to-csv
- orgtbl-to-generic
- orgtbl-to-html
- orgtbl-to-latex
- orgtbl-to-orgtbl
- orgtbl-to-texinfo
- orgtbl-to-tsv

Comment: OP already said this is unacceptable, as in looking for a better way.